# Can default product quantity of 1 be enabled with Opportunity settings via Metadata API?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, package, unlocked-package, scratch-org-definition-file

From the UI, there is a setting that can be enabled: `Setup > Opportunity Settings > When users add a product to an opportunity, insert a quantity of 1`

I cannot find a way to enable this via Metadata API, and I also cannot find confirmation that this is unavailable via Metadata API. I specifically need this enabled to build a package that depends on that setting, but as far as I know, I have no way to specify that it should be enabled in my definition file either. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked with concern team and currently this feature is on future road map with Work Item *#*W-8248530** and will be available in coming releases. However, we do not have any ETA on when this feature will be available.

For now, there is no way to expose 'When users add a product to an opportunity, insert a quantity of 1' [opportunity setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_opportunityssettings.htm) using metadata API.